# PHP RecursiveArrayIterator Get current depth

Tags: php, arrays

I am processing [this array](http://pastebin.com/DxGAeHyZ) with RecursiveArrayIterator using this:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($array),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach ($iterator as $key => $item) {
    //not working
    //echo $iterator->getDepth() . "\n";

}
```

Is it possible to get the current depth while I am going through the array using that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my data was coming from an XML source I was able to solve my problem with:

```
$sxi = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
           new SimpleXMLIterator($xml), 
           RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($sxi as $key => $value) {
    $currentDepth = $sxi->getDepth();
}
```